# trying to send a get request but CORS messing things up

Tags: cors, fetch-api

i have been trying for ONE HOUR to send a request

```
;(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=2;host=6;opposition=5;team=6;template=results;type=batting', {
      method: 'GET',
    })
console.log(response)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

})()
```

it hasn't worked a single time

I can't make out anything from the error it gives me either.

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at main.js:13:28
    at main.js:21:3
```

i also tried looking into the network tab but shows nothing new

Comment: "nothing new" - what _does_ it show? How do you know it's CORS then? If it is, that means you are simply not allowed to send that request from another website. Send it from a server instead. (Unless you own `stats.espncricinfo.com`, in this case modify your web server to return the CORS headers you need.)

Comment: it just shows red text and says "cors error"

Comment: My browser console gives a clear error message explicitly pointing out the CORS issue, when I try to make that request.

Comment: what does it say?

Comment: Did you look in your _own_ console tab? (have it open while the error occurs) Make sure you don't have any filter on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request does not work because your origin (where you run that code) is not allowed.

Permissions of this nature are controlled by CORS headers. You can read more about CORS at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and many other places.

The code and URL you are using is correct. The problem is *where* you use that code.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the URL you are trying to fetch that URL might be incorrect or may contain some error so double-check it once again.

Comment: While this is one possible source of the error, it's merely speculation. Answers should provide a definite solution. This would be better placed as a comment.